# how to display images and text into viewpager from url using JSON

Tags: android

Can anyone give an proper example how to display images and text from URL into viewPager. I do not find any complete example from where i can get idea. i am new to android, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/10/image-gallery-by-viewpager-android.html

Comment: Do you know how to parse text and image url from JSON?

Comment: yes , but i dont know how to dispaly images and text in viewpager

Comment: @Divyesh and your links are not with JSON

Comment: but you can set JSON data into it

Comment: Adding in Divyesh's comment, @manpreetkaur you can parse and store the url and the caption in a `HashMap` later you can pass this map to the [Slider, See Sample Here](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/demo%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fdaimajia%2Fslider%2Fdemo%2FMainActivity.java)

Answer (score 3):

**We can split this into parts**

**1. Getting Json data from the url**

> you can use volley plugin to get json data from url, for adding plugin 
>   to android studio do the following

In android studio, open your build.gradle(Module:app) file under Gradle Scripts , add the following line in dependencies and sync the Gradle

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

**2. Setting response values to views(ie, image url to imageview,and text value to edittext/textview etc)**

> you can use Picasso plugin to set an image to Imageview from url. you
>   need to add the following line in build.gradle (Module:app) file .it
>   is same as the procedures we done to add volley plugin. and sync the
>   gradle

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

**Let's Assume your Json Data In url is like the below one**

```
{
    "image_url": "https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg",
    "text_value": "some text"
}
```

**Do this in your java page:-**

```
String url = "your_url_to_the_json_data";


// Request a string response, 
// you will get response from url as string


           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                   new Response.Listener<String>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onResponse(String response) {


                           // you will get the response as string here
                           //String response holds the response from url

                          Log.d("response from url",response);
                         try
                         {

                          //converting string response to json object
                          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);


                          String my_text_value=jsonObject.getString("text_value");

                          String my_image_url=jsonObject.getString("image_url");

                          // now you got your text and image urls in the above strings


                          //now set it your imageview and edittext

                          my_edittext.setText(my_text_value);

                          //An external plugin named picasso is used to set image to an imageview from pic url

                          Picasso.with(this).load(my_image_url).into(my_imageview);


                          }

                          catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "json exception",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }



                       }
                   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   //this part will work if there is any error

                   System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
                   error.printStackTrace();

               }

           })
           {
               @Override
               protected Map<String, String> getParams()
               {
                   Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                   //you can pass parameters ,if you want to

                   //in this case its not needed


                   //params.put("parameter1", value1);
                  // params.put("parameter2",value2);



                   return params;
               }
           };


           // Add the request to the queue

           Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

**Don't forget To change the following values with your values**

```
* `String url = "your_url_to_the_json_data";`

   change `"your_url_to_the_json_data"` with your url

* `my_edittext.setText(my_text_value);`

    change `my_edittext` to your edittext or textView object

* `Picasso.with(this).load(my_image_url).into(my_imageview);`

  change `my_imageview` to your imageview object
```

Comment: Fragments are used as Pages in Viewpager , So you can use the above code in Fragment . Only thing you need to change is Change 'this' with 'getActivity' .

Answer (score 0):

You can load images from url into an ImageView using Picasso, and just by using one line in android. You will have to put this in your gradle to include picasso in your project.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And you need to put this line your code which loads the image. You can also resize the image, use a dummy image in imageView until the pic from url loads just in the same command.

```
Picasso.with(this).load("here goes the url").into(userPic);
```

Assuming that you can get the text by sending a GET request at a particular url,  you can use volley android library for this purpose.

```
//You will need to do something like this
//Create a new RequestQueue in your activity
RequestQueue queue = Volley.new RequestQueue(context);

//Create the get request
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"here goes the url", 
new Response.Listener<String>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // response is the text response you will receive
        textView.setText(response.toString());
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         // error
         textView.setText("Error Received:- "+error.toString());
   }
})};

//add the current get request in the request queue
queue.add(postRequest);
```